Why Does This Haskell Closure Keep Giving Me 'No instance for (Integral (IO t0))' Error?
Dear StackExchange Experts,
I have been trying to learn how to program in Haskell from the book 'Get Programming With Haskell', and I came across an example involving closures from Chapter 5. I tried implementing it as below:
ifEven func x = if even x then func x else x


genIfEven x  = (\func -> ifEven func x)

testfunc1 :: Num a => a -> a
testfunc1 x = x+2

main = do{

  genIfEven 3 testfunc1
  }

Unfortunately, though it was an example in the book, the compiler keeps rejecting it due to typing reasons (No instance for (Integral (IO t0)) arising from a use of ‘genIfEven’) that I don't even understand yet.
Is there anyone who could explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and point out to me how I could fix this code so that it works?  :)

genIfEven 3 testfunc1 is an integer, but main should be an IO (). Did you forget to print it?

@NaïmFavier, OK, you're right, I didn't print it! Rookie mistake from a rookie :( I didn't really understand the error message, but I guess that's because I've been too coddled by Python :(
If you put this comment as the answer (And explained why the error message is so complicated to me), I would certainly mark it as answering my question :)

That expression has type forall a. Integral a => a; that is, it can have any type you want as long as that type is an Integral. The expected type there is IO t0, but that's not an Integral type, so GHC complains. You'd get a similar error if you did main = 42, because number literals have type forall a. Num a => a.

@AnonAnon An expert Haskeller who was completely new to Python (or any language like it) wouldn't understand Python error messages at first either. Learning the terminology used in error messages is part of learning a language; you can't expect to just automatically understand them. But don't think that Haskell error messages are inherently bad or unclear; they're actually very good in my experience, but what makes them good is that they contain a lot of precisely specified information, which is exactly what makes them intimidating when you don't yet understand all the information.

Two unrelated points I'd make about your code: 1) please include explicit type signatures for all your functions (as you do for testfunc1, but not ifEven or genIfEven. Although it wouldn't have helped on this occasion, doing this can make error messages about types MUCH easier to understand. 2) this is more likely just something you'll pick up as you get more comfortable with Haskell, but genIfEven has quite a verbose definition, an experienced Haskeller would write it as genifEven = flip ifEven - it's literally the same function but takes its 2 arguments in the opposite order.

You'd get approximately the same error if you wrote:
main = 3

All the rest of your code is just hiding this core problem, so I'll explain why this isn't right and how the compiler is trying to explain that to you.
The short answer to why it isn't right is: it's not doing any IO (not even the do-nothing IO you get from pure/return). Your main is required to do some IO. You could fix this by writing, for example,
main = pure 3
-- OR
main = print 3

But the short answer isn't quite right, because if the type of 3 isn't IO _, then what is it? Let's ask ghci:
> :t 3
3 :: Num a => a

There isn't really a single, simple type that 3 has! Any type that has an instance of the Num typeclass is plausible. In the standard library, these are types like Int, Integer, Word16, Double, and so forth.
Here's the problem: it's legal (though rare for many reasons) to declare an instance of Num for IO actions! In the presence of such an instance, main = 3 would be a valid program after all. So the type mismatch is latent. Returning to your exact error:
No instance for (Integral (IO t0)) arising from a use of ‘genIfEven’

This is using the Integral class, rather than the Num class (because you used even), but the core idea is essentially the same: if only there were an Integral instance for IO actions, your program would be legal. But there isn't, so it ain't.
